# Sum of the series $\sum_{i=1}^n a^i i^r$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

How can I find the sum of the series :

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a^ii^r $$

Comment: That's a finite sum, not series... What is $r$?

Comment: r is a postive integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $r$ is a positive integer...

$$S_0(a) = \sum_{i=1}^n a^i = a \frac{a^{n}-1}{a-1} $$

$$S_1(a) = \sum_{i=1}^n i a^i = a \frac{d}{da} S_0(a) $$

$$S_2(a) =\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 a^i = a \frac{d}{da} \left [a \frac{d}{da}\right] S_0(a) $$

$$\cdots$$

$$S_r(a) =\sum_{i=1}^n i^r a^i = \left [a \frac{d}{da}\right]^r S_0(a) $$

Comment: here $$\frac{d}{da}$$ is the derivative w.r.t to `a` right ?

Comment: @AbhishekGupta: yes

Comment: what if r > n ? , will this formula hold ?

Comment: @AbhishekGupta: yes.  Why wouldn't it?

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong but the rth derivative in that case would be zero,
if i look at it as series a + a^2 + a^3 ...
and if then differentiate r times it would be
 0 + 0 + 0 +...

Comment: @AbhishekGupta: you are not just differentiating but applying the operator $a \frac{d}{da}$ $r$ times.